# Letter Rack 8x5 number 1

Tags: word

There is an 8-letter word in here, reading from top to bottom, picking one letter from each row.

> ```
> a b c d e  
> t u v w x  
> l m n o p  
> d e f g h  
> a b c d e  
> i j k l m  
> n o p q r  
> t u v w x
> ```

Can you tell me what it is?

Comment: I suppose "no-computers" would be an appropriate tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is

> bungalow.

Using this pattern:

> ```
>  a *b  c  d  e
>
>  t *u  v  w  x
>
>  l  m *n  o  p
>
>  d  e  f *g  h
>
>  *a  b  c  d  e
>
>  i  j  k *l  m
>
>  n *o  p  q  r
>
>  t  u  v *w  x
> ```